# Locate disk in SAS enclosure

Tags: external-hdd, scsi

I want to blink the failing device in my 24-disk SAS enclosure.

I have found `sg_ses --index 7 --set=locate /dev/sg24` which is supposed to identify slot 7.

But how do I figure out which slot/index `/dev/sdh` is?

This is not obvious as Linux does not name /dev/sdX after the slot, but after the sequence it was detected. Think what happens if slot 1 is empty at boot, but is filled later.

Edit:

The controller is a SAS2008.

Comment: This is completely dependent upon your array controller hardware. You need to tell us what that is.

Comment: I checked my system (Sles11 sp2), the sg_ses doesn't have a `--index` and `--set` as input params, and there is no `/sys/class/enclosure*` in the sles11 sp2. What's your Linux environment? Did you install other utilities in the OS by yourself?

Comment: Debian Stable: Linux server 3.2.0-0.bpo.1-amd64

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After cycling around /sys for a while, I found this solution:

```
# echo /sys/class/enclosure/*/*/device/block/sdaa
/sys/class/enclosure/2:0:35:0/Slot 15/device/block/sdaa
# echo 1 > '/sys/class/enclosure/2:0:35:0/Slot 15/locate'
```

Or:

```
# echo 1 > /sys/class/enclosure/*/*/device/block/sdaa/../../enclosure*/locate
```

To blink all detected devices:

```
parallel echo 1 \> ::: /sys/class/enclosure/*/*/device/block/sd*/../../enclosure*/locate
```

This is useful if you have a drive that is so broken that is not even detected by Linux (e.g. it does not spin up).

Edit:

I have made a small tool (called blink) to blink slots. https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/tree/master/blink

Answer (score 4):

This ugly script adds enclosure and slot information to `lsblk` output:

```
lsblk -d -o VENDOR,MODEL,SERIAL,HCTL,NAME | sed -e "`ls -1d /sys/class/enclosure/*/*/device/block/*|sed "s+.*enclosure/\(.*\)/device/block/\(.*\)+s-\2\\$-\2 \1-+"`"
```

(you can change list of columns, but last column should be `NAME`)

Answer (score 3):

Check what `/sys/class/block/sdh` links to. You can see the host, target and LUN this way. Usually this is enough to pinpoint the device's hardware address.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to /sys. As you can see the solution is a bit more involved.

Comment: @OleTange Ok. You should post your solution as an answer, please don't post answers in questions as they are not easily visible to future visitors. It's [OK to  ask and answer your own question.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq). I'll leave my answer because it shows the general approach, but you should accept your own answer (when the system lets you, there's a delay) since it's more complete for this particular task on this particular enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

lsscsi can give you this information.

```
lsscsi -g
```

will return the /dev/sgX address beside the /dev/sdX address.

Comment: Please expand on what information this command provides and how that answers the question.  Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice tool encled (available at https://github.com/amarao/sdled) to manage your enclosure led's.

You should be able to use it like this (not tested, though):

```
encled /dev/sgh fault
```

From the README:

> fault - set led indicator to 'faulty'.
>   This WILL NOT make device faulty, just set
>   enclosure led to 'FAULTY' status.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We like answers to be more comprehensive here. Could you edit your answer and provide an example of how the OP could use this tool to achieve their objective? As it stands, it is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: Look, if I have a tool and know where I can find this tool, whats wrong with answer? I definitely know that edited answer is wrong, since initially author of this question requested a locate led. But, anyway, this answer provide much easiest way to made led on enclosure blink than previous.